# Console read input

Tags: vb.net, console-application

How to create a console application which would read input from user and assign the input to a variable? The problem is, I need to enter several words on one line separated with blank spaces like "*ab cd efg*" and then assign ab to one variable, cd to another variable and efg to another variable. Also the entered words can be any lenght.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
Dim tokens As String() = input.Split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this homework? I'll keep the answer from being too concrete, but you will want to learn more about [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) and [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx). We can start there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx), [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) and [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) methods to accomplish this task.

Good luck.